# Chart.JS custom legend onClick event returns error when calling original event handler

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have 2 charts. First one is bar chart and it works with same code. Second one is pie chart and it doesn't work.

I'm trying to create custom onClick handler for pie chart legend and I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_resolveAnimations' of null
at Chart._updateDatasetVisibility (chart.esm.js:5677)
at Chart.show (chart.esm.js:5686)
at Object.onClick (chart.esm.js:7798)
at Legend.onClick (analytics.component.ts:529)
at callback (helpers.segment.js:89)
at Legend.handleEvent (chart.esm.js:7744)
at Object.afterEvent (chart.esm.js:7781)
at callback (helpers.segment.js:89)
at PluginService._notify (chart.esm.js:4774)
at PluginService.notify (chart.esm.js:4761)
```

Below you can see code for onClick handler

```
legend: {
        onClick: (e: any, legendItem: { text: string; }, legend: any) => {
          /**
           * Stores original event handler for legend onClick 
           * and executes it so we don't override it.
           */
          Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick(e, legendItem, legend);

          /**
           * Custom legend item handler
           */
          let toBeRemoved = this.consumption.find((c) => c.categoryName === legendItem.text);
          let toBeRemovedIndex = this.consumption.indexOf(toBeRemoved);

          if (toBeRemoved) {
            // Hide consumption item from table
            this.hideConsumptionItem(toBeRemoved, toBeRemovedIndex);
            // Recalculate consumption sum
            this.recalculateConsumptionSum();
          } else {
            // Restore hidden item from saved items
            this.restoreConsumptionItem(legendItem);
            // Recalculate consumption sum
            this.recalculateConsumptionSum();
          }
        },
        labels: {
          fontColor: '#4f4f51',
          padding: this.deviceService.isDesktopDisplay() ? 10 : 6,
          boxWidth: this.deviceService.isDesktopDisplay() ? 40 : 15,
          fontSize: this.deviceService.isDesktopDisplay() ? 12 : 8,
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              display: false
            }
          }]
        },
        title: {
          display: false
        }
      },
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work fine, although the rest of your config is slightly wrong, the scales and title object dont belong in the legend object and the scales are no arrays anymore.

Working example of default click:

```js
// dummy array and methods so no errors
const consumption = [];
const recalculateConsumptionSum = () => {};
const restoreConsumptionItem = (e) => {};

var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      /* x: {  comment scale config out because we dont want the x axis lines behind our douhgnut
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      } */
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onClick: (e, legendItem, legend) => {
          /**
           * Stores original event handler for legend onClick 
           * and executes it so we don't override it.
           */
          if (legend.chart.config.type === 'pie' || legend.chart.config.type === 'doughnut') {
            Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.onClick(e, legendItem, legend)
          } else {
            Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick(e, legendItem, legend);
          }

          /**
           * Custom legend item handler
           */
          let toBeRemoved = consumption.find((c) => c.categoryName === legendItem.text);
          let toBeRemovedIndex = consumption.indexOf(toBeRemoved);

          if (toBeRemoved) {
            // Hide consumption item from table
            this.hideConsumptionItem(toBeRemoved, toBeRemovedIndex);
            // Recalculate consumption sum
            this.recalculateConsumptionSum();
          } else {
            // Restore hidden item from saved items
            restoreConsumptionItem(legendItem);
            // Recalculate consumption sum
            recalculateConsumptionSum();
          }
        },
        labels: {
          color: '#4f4f51',
          padding: 10,
          boxWidth: 40,
          font: {
            size: 12
          }
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It works on 'line' and 'bar' chart but it does not work if you change it to 'pie' chart. Pie chart is returning errors.

Comment: Thats because the doughnut and pie chart controller override the default onClick handler for the legend because they behave differently so you will need to get that handler out of the controller, see updated answer

Comment: "Chart.controllers" are undefined so it cannot run Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct for lower version but the right solution is to use 
Chart.overrides.pie.plugins.legend.onClick
instead of 
Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.onClick

Comment: I have updated your answer with this fix.

Comment: idk what you mean, the sample is litterly using the latest version of chart.js and it works?